# How to access further members of an array when using bash variable indirection?

Tags: bash, bash-expansion, bash-array, indirection

Consider the following example, it seems it's working fine with the index `0`:

```
$ a1=(1 2 3)
$ a2=(a b c)
$ for x in a1 a2; do echo "${!x}"; done
1
a
$ for x in a1 a2; do echo "${!x[0]}"; done
1
a
```

However with the index `1` it prints nothing:

```
$ for x in a1 a2; do echo "${!x[1]}"; done
```

Arrays just by themselves are fine:

```
$ echo "${a1[1]} ${a2[1]}"
2 b
```

#### Edit - A real life use case based on *ilkkachu* answer

```
SHIBB=(https://shibboleth.net/downloads/service-provider/3.0.2/ shibboleth-sp-3.0.2 .tar.gz)
XERCES=(http://apache.mirrors.nublue.co.uk//xerces/c/3/sources/ xerces-c-3.2.1 .tar.gz)
XMLSEC=(http://apache.mirror.anlx.net/santuario/c-library/ xml-security-c-2.0.1 .tar.gz)
XMLTOOL=(http://shibboleth.net/downloads/c++-opensaml/latest/ xmltooling-3.0.2 .tar.gz)
OPENSAML=(http://shibboleth.net/downloads/c++-opensaml/latest/ opensaml-3.0.0 .tar.gz)

typeset -n x
for x in XERCES XMLSEC XMLTOOL OPENSAML SHIBB; do
  url="${x[0]}" app="${x[1]}" ext="${x[2]}"
  [ -f "./${app}${ext}" ] || wget "${url}${app}${ext}"
  tar -xf "./${app}${ext}"
  cd "./${app}" && ./configure && make -j2 && make install && ldconfig
  cd ..
done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"${!x[1]}"` is an indirect reference using the element at index `1` of the array `x`.

```
$ foo=123; bar=456; x=(foo bar); echo "${!x[1]}"
456
```

In current versions of Bash (4.3 and above), you can use namerefs to get what you want:

```
$ a=(00 11 22 33 44)
$ typeset -n y=a
$ echo "${y[3]}"
33
```

that is, with the nameref set up, `"${y[3]}"` is a reference to element `3` in the array named by `y`.

---

To loop over the arrays as you do in your question, you'd simply make `x` a nameref.

```
a1=(1 2 3); a2=(a b c)
typeset -n x;
for x in a1 a2; do
    echo "${x[1]}"
done
```

The assignments done by the `for` loop change the value of `x` itself (changing what the reference points to). A regular assignment (`x=123`, or `x[1]=123`) changes the variable currently referenced by `x`. So this would change both `a1[1]` and `a2[1]` to `foo`:

```
typeset -n x;
for x in a1 a2; do
    x[1]=foo
done
```

---

The reason `"${!x[0]}"` seems to work is that `x` and `x[0]` are equivalent. If you had `echo "${x[0]}"` inside your loop (without the bang), you'd get `a1`, `a2`, the same as with `echo "$x"`.

Comment: Could you please give an example how to use `typeset -n` in the `for` loop, just like I showed in the question?

Comment: @NarūnasK, edited. Though I do wonder what your actual use case is. Looping over array names like that seems a bit quaint.

Comment: I have a bunch of the tarballs, which I have to download, unpack, cd into the directory, configure/make... Basically very repetitive steps, which now (thanks to you) fit in the for loop very nicely :) Please see edited question.